# Multiple SQL table value parameter pass into a single store procedure using ado.net

Tags: stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have a single store procedure & it has 4 parameters.Two parameters are table value parameter which pass by user & other's two parameters are output.One is string data type which variable name is message & another is int data type also named by status.So i wanna to pass 4 parameter by ado.net.But i don't know why vs show this error.

"Operand type clash: dbo.tvpPurchase is incompatible with dbo.tvpPurchaseDetail"

Here is my code in below

```
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        var status = 0;
        var message = "";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "dbo.spPurchaseDataMaipulation";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parameter;
                parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchaseType", CreateSqlDataRecordsForPurchase(purlist));
                Parameter = Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchaseDetailType", CreateSqlDataRecordsForPurchaseDetail(purDetai));
                Command.Parameters.Add("@message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);
                Command.Parameters["@message"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                Command.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int);
                Command.Parameters["@status"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                parameter.TypeName = "dbo.tvpPurchase";
                parameter.TypeName = "dbo.tvpPurchaseDetail";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                status = Convert.ToInt32(Command.Parameters["@status"].Value);
                message = Command.Parameters["@message"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        return new { status = status,message = message};
```

Comment: `parameter` & "`Parameter`" need to be separate variables, setting `parameter.TypeName` twice for example makes little sense.

Comment: thanks Alex K. i understand what will  do now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the same reference for both table valued parameters. You can avoid that problem and simplify your code like this.

Instead of using `AddWithValue`, you can simply use this overload of [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx) - it returns a reference to the parameter you've just added. This will make your code shorter and easier:

```
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "dbo.spPurchaseDataMaipulation";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter parameter;
    command.Parameters.Add("@purchaseType", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = CreateSqlDataRecordsForPurchase(purlist);
    command.Parameters.Add("@purchaseDetailType", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = CreateSqlDataRecordsForPurchaseDetail(purDetai);
    Command.Parameters.Add("@message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    Command.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    status = Convert.ToInt32(Command.Parameters["@status"].Value);
    message = Command.Parameters["@message"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Further reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)